# Learning to programming JavaScript, but I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Yesterday I started learning JavaScript. I am using the system [Codecademy](http://codecademy.com), but I'm stuck. When I say "stuck", I mean I have assignment with which I cannot see what is wrong.

**The assignment is:**

Create an array, `myArray`. Its first element should be a number, its second should be a boolean, its third should be a string, and its fourth should be...an object! You can add as many elements of any type as you like after these first four.

**This is the code I made:**

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'Hansen'
};

var myArray = [12,true, "Steen" ,myObj.name];
```

**The error:**

> Oops, try again. 
>   Is the fourth element of myArray an object?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: @Kevin I rolled back your edit to the question because it completely changed the question and the answers no longer made sense. I see that it was a follow-up question to your original one. Stack Overflow works best if you keep to one problem per question. You can link to previous questions for context if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your fourth element is you are passing a string because `myObj.name` is defined as `Hansen`. Pass the object instead:

```
var myArray = [12,true, "Steen" ,myObj];
```

Comment: THanks! Should have asked before :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that site, but you can do:

```
var myArray = [
    12,
    true,
    "Steen",
    {name: 'Hansen'}
];
```

What you are passing to the array is the value of the `name` property of your object instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing in the name property instead of the object for the fourth array parameter as you probably already know from the other anwers.

As your learning here are a few ways to do exactly the same thing as your accomplishing here.

**Your way corrected:**

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'Hansen'
};

var myArray = [12, true, "Steen", myObj];
```

**Other ways:**

```
// Method 1
var myArray = [12, true, "Steen", {name: 'Hansen'}];

// Method 2
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.name = "Hansen";
var myArray = new Array(12, true, "Steen", myObj);

// Method 3
var myObj = {};
myObj['name'] = 'Hansen'
var myArray = [
    12, true, 'Steen', myObj
]
```

Each method shows a few different ways to do the same thing, you can mix and match the equivalent parts of code to get the same job done. It's basically inter changing between the normal JavaScript syntax and **object literal syntax**.